# Firebase - limit service account IAM to one db

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-iam

I have a Firebase Realtime Database that I connect to from my Java application using the Admin SDK.
In my project I have multiple databases, but for administrative reasons, I want to create separate service accounts for each one. In other words, I want the service account to have full database access, but only to one particular database.

I was hoping this could be done through Google Cloud IAM but I am having trouble finding how. I tried adding giving the service account "Firebase Realtime Database Admin" permission but with a condition of Name = `//mydbname.firebaseio.com` but that doesn't work. That is, my Java backend is not able to connect to the database with that condition in place.

Am I on the right track, just using the wrong name? Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

**There currently is no way to do control access per database instance through IAM.** It sounds like a reasonable feature though, so I recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) for it.

The best I can think of for now is to [authenticate with limited privileges](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges) when you initialize the Admin SDK and then check that identity in the security rules of each instance, but that means that the code could also choose to not pass a UID, which may be exactly what you're trying to avoid.

Comment: Thanks. Quick follow up - if I am using the Admin SDK with a service account that I created myself, does that not have full write access on the database? Do I need to authorize it with rules? If so that's actually fine but how do I identify it? Does it have a "uid"?

Comment: Yup, the Admin SDK indeed gives full access. Realtime Database allows you to limit that access by specifying a UID when you initialize it as shown in the link, which is then a value you can check for in the rules (with `auth.uid`). I typically set the UID to something readable in this code, like `cloud_functions` or `admin_server`.